# making image ready for Tesseract_OCR

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

Im new to computer-vision field. Im trying to make my image easily Recognize by OCR. i already did many steps to make it easy for Tesseract_OCR to recognize but in vain. Kindly someone help me.

this is my original image [input.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y87f.jpg)

Sorry im not good at this but any help will be grateful thank you

that is the code

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

alpha = 3.0
beta = -150
new = alpha * gray + beta
new = np.clip(new, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(new, (3, 3), 0)

dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(blur, None, 3, 7, 21)

se=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT , (1,1))

bg=cv2.morphologyEx(dst, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, se)
```

this is my output image but it still did not coming to my expectation[output.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQOdy.jpg)

Also i did this too ..

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
alpha = 4.0
beta = -200
new = alpha * gray + beta
new = np.clip(new, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(new, (3, 3), 0)

dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(blur, None, 3, 7, 21)

th1 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(dst, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)

se=cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT , (1,1))

bg=cv2.morphologyEx(th1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, se)
```

output is this[output.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjoKA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can do division normalization in Python/OpenCV on your image before any other processing.

- Read the input
- Convert to grayscale
- Blur the grayscale image
- Divide the grayscale image by the blurred image
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('text_img.jpg')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# blur
smooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, None, sigmaX=30, sigmaY=30)

# divide gray by morphology image
division = cv2.divide(gray, smooth, scale=255)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('text_img_division.jpg',division)

# show results
cv2.imshow('smooth', smooth)  
cv2.imshow('division', division)  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Resulting Image:

[image]